# count(*) query issue

Tags: mysql, count

I have a table with these records:

```
id         code        date
-----      ------      -----
1          12          2016-01-01
2          12          2016-01-02
3          17          2016-01-03
4          12          2016-01-04
5          17          2016-01-05
6          17          2016-01-06
7          17          2016-01-07
```

I use this query:

```
SELECT `id`, `code`, `date`, COUNT(*) AS total 
FROM `foo` 
GROUP BY (code) 
ORDER BY (id) DESC
```

and I get this:

```
id         code        date           total
-----      ------      ------         ------
3          17          2016-01-03     4
1          12          2016-01-01     3
```

But I need to display this:

```
id         code        date           total
-----      ------      ------         ------
7          17          2016-01-07     4
4          12          2016-01-04     3
```

Is it possible? Thank you very much.

Comment: Please use tags properly. sql-server is Microsoft SQL Server and if your question is about MySQL, you should not use sql-server

Comment: How come your query works? you have id, code and date in SELECT clause without having them in GROUP BY clause!!

Comment: @FLICKER, I believe MySQL allows that. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/05047d/4/0).

Comment: @FelixPamittan, Weird. This is against standard sql, BTW, if it is not in group by, which value will be returned for id and date? the first one, the last one or random?!

Comment: Yeah, that's what I don't know.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `MAX` function:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/05047d/3/0)

```
SELECT
    MAX(id) AS id,
    code,
    MAX(date) AS date,
    COUNT(*) AS total
FROM foo
GROUP BY code
ORDER BY MAX(id) DESC;
```

Comment: In what scenario might this be useful?

Comment: I need to display the number of times that a record appear in the table, grouped by code, and I need to display with php when was the last time it appeared..